# Using Rspec to test ActiveRecord validations for similar fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bdd, rails-activerecord, rspec-rails

I recently started learning RoR and TDD, and am having trouble figuring out the best way to handle this scenario.

I have an ActiveRecord model with two fields which share the same validations.

How do I write an RSpec test which utilizes the same tests for the similar fields?

"shared examples" looked like a promising feature to utilize in this scenario, but does not seem to work, as I need to test the entire model but am only passing the individual field to the shared example.

Below is my failed attempt:

```
describe Trip do
  before do
    @trip = trip.new(date: '2013-07-01', city_1: "PORTLAND", 
            city_2: "BOSTON")
  end

  subject { @trip }

  shared_examples "a city" do
    describe "when not uppercase" do
      before { city = city.downcase }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end
  end

  describe "city_1 must be valid" do
    it_should_behave_like "a city" do
      let!(:city) { @trip.city_1}
    end
  end

  describe "city_2 must be valid" do
    it_behaves_like "a city" do
      let!(:city) { @trip.city_2}
    end
  end
end
```

This fails because updating the city variable does not update trip model.  Is there a way to dynamically tie it back to the model?

BTW, all the tests work on their own if I paste under each field.  It just will not work in the context of the shared_example.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the assertion within a loop, and use a little metaprogramming, but I would advise against it. Tests should be as simple and straightforward as possible, even if that means having a little duplication. If only two fields are involved, just repeat it.